# Wamp won't enable sodium extension

Tags: php, wamp, magento2

I'm trying to install magento2 on my wampserver 3.3.0 and I have to enable sodium extenssion in wamp its easy just click wampserver icon find php find php extensions and enable sodium extension, my problem here when I tried to run this command to see which modules are enabled `php -m` in my case the sodium extension is not there, but if I open localhost and chose php extension I see sodium extension enabled. I don't know what I'm doing wrong to enable sodium extension in cmd.

note: I already check my php.ini file and sodium extension show enabled without semi-colons

I hope somebody helps many thanks

I'm trying to solve my problem with wampserver installing magento2

[Here is my wamp show enabled sodium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11Q6H.jpg)

[Here is my PHP.ini file with sodium active as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSB62.jpg)

Comment: PHP embedded into the webserver, and PHP CLI, often use two different php.ini files. Run `php --ini`, and check for "Loaded Configuration File". You will have to enable the extension in that one, if you want it to be available in PHP CLI.

Comment: Hy thanks for the answer, I run php --ini and this is the result

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.2.0\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: That is a different path than the one you got opened in NotePad++ there in your screenshot.

Comment: Can you point the right folders path?

Comment: It's using the php.ini from the path you quoted there, so that is the one you need to modify for changes regarding the PHP CLI configuration.